# Android:gravity parameter of layout not showing any effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I am using to implement CustomAdapter to populate listview  data. And for each item I am trying to customize the layoutparams of textview . But layoutparams.gravity is not working in my code. Below is the code snippet which I am using

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        User user= getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        }   
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        tvName.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        tvName.setText(getStringFromXmlByName(user.getTitle()));
        tvName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tvName.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));

        return convertView;
    } 

private LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(convertDpIntoPixels(300),
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        return layoutParams;

    }

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Gravity** specifies how the contents of a View is to be laid out ***within itself***.

**Layout Gravity** specifies how the View is to be laid out ***within it's parent***.

What your code does is sets the text inside the TextView to be laid out in the center, horizontally, within the TextView that wraps it's own content. So essentially there's nothing for gravity to do as the bounds of the TextView completely hug the text.

What I suspect you are trying to do is center the TextView within the parent. For this you need to either set **gravity** on the **parent** to `center_horizontal` or set the **layout_gravity** of the **TextView** to `center_horizontal`.

Comment: i understand that thing . . therefore I have specified gravity of payout not working !

Comment: Set gravity in the layout xml file, no need to do it in code. Post a screenshot.

Comment: layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; is the line which is not working as desired

Comment: parent is sticking to default left side !!

Comment: gravity in the layout xml file cannot be set because it has to be done dynamically

Comment: That's not true at all. You are constraining the TextView to 300dp width, you can do that in xml. You can also set gravity on the parent LinearLayout to right to get the text to float right.

Comment: actually the pattern is zig zag which needs to be implemented .  . so i need to set the floating parameter programatically

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: gravity has be set dynamically

Comment: u r giving gravity to text view not liner layout and your textview also wrap_contant gravity is not apply on wrap_content